# Arduino - Serial Communication - error in the code

Tags: c#, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

My goal is to make a project that can be able to control a simple system using the NodeMcu esp 8266, by a another simple Windows Form Application in C#.
But I had some mistakes on my code and I don't know why. So I would like to someone help me doing this.
Errors:

1. When I sent the position to the servo, he works only one time and every time in the same position.
2. When I sent the comand to the Bulbs turn on off, only one of them works.
3. Just the buzzer works as I want

Here is the Arduino Code:

```
// Programação do controle de dispositivos via Serial com ESP8266

#include <Servo.h>
// #include <Process.h>

Servo servo;

const int buzzer = D2;
const int lamp1 = D4;
const int lamp2 = D0;
const int pinServo = D3;

String serialData;

// String comando;

bool estadoBuzzer = LOW;
bool estadoLam1 = LOW;
bool estadoLam2 = LOW;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //SerialUSB.begin(115200);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lamp1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lamp2, OUTPUT);
  servo.attach(pinServo);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
  //Bridge.begin();
  //while (!SerialUSB);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  serialEvent(Serial.readString());
}

void serialEvent(String data){
  /*Process p;
  comando = "echo " + data + " > teste_arduino_serial_comandos.txt";
  p.runShellCommand(comando);
  */
  if(data.charAt(0) == 'B'){
    if(estadoBuzzer == HIGH){
      digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
      estadoBuzzer = LOW;
    } else {
      digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
      estadoBuzzer = HIGH;
    }
  } else if(data.charAt(0) == 'L'){
    data.remove(0);
    if(data.toInt() == 1){
      lampada1();
    } else {
      lampada2();
    }
  } else if(data.charAt(0) == 'A'){
    data.remove(0);
    int angulo = data.toInt();
    Serial.println(angulo);
    if(angulo >= 0 && angulo <= 180){
      servo.write(angulo);
    }
  }
}

void lampada1(){
  if(estadoLam1 == HIGH){
     digitalWrite(lamp1, LOW);
     estadoLam1 = LOW;
  } else {
     digitalWrite(lamp1, HIGH);
     estadoLam1 = HIGH;
  }
}

void lampada2(){
  if(estadoLam2 == HIGH){
     digitalWrite(lamp2, LOW);
     estadoLam2 = LOW;
  }
  else {
     digitalWrite(lamp2, HIGH);
     estadoLam2 = HIGH;
  }
}
```

And here is the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ControleDeDispositivosViaSerialNodeMcuEsp8266
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Stopwatch watch { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            port.Open();
        }
        public void writeToPort(String indicador, String valor="0")
        {

            if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 15)
            {
                watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                port.Write(String.Format(indicador+valor));

                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(indicador + valor);

            }
            // System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(port.ReadExisting());
        }

        private void anguloBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            writeToPort("A", angulos.Text);
            angulos.Refresh();

        }

        private void onoff1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            writeToPort("L", "1");
        }

        private void onoff2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            writeToPort("L", "2");
        }

        private void buzzerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            writeToPort("B");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: String is a type of variables

Comment: Oh, now I understood you.... String in C "does not exist", but when we use string in Arduino, it doesn't work, so we have to use String

Comment: perhaps readString returns after reading just the first character. Maybe you should send a length and then loop till you receive all the data (long time since I wrote any arduino code) (or always send , say 4 character)

Answer (score 0):

Your data.toInt() is not working, this is why it gets always only one lamp and to same postion on the servo.

The data.Remove(0) is removing all after first char so will be empty.

Use data = data. Substring(1)

What i normally do as feedback to check is write: Serial.println(data) etcto check if i really work with what i think i have.

Comment: Thank you very much, even though my problem is not solven yet . . . But you helped a few much . .